# Send a image file to a particular friend in my friends list

Tags: android

i am doing a sample Facebook application in that i post a image file to a particular friend in my friends list, if any one having the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code..i put the stream.publish method inside the request function..it works well..

```
 protected void postToWall(String temp2) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
   params.putString("message", _messageInput.getText().toString()"some text Here);
   params.putString("caption", "{*actor*} just posted a secret message.");
   params.putString("description","A secret message is waiting for you.  Click the link to      decode it.");
   params.putString("name", "A Secret Message For You");
   params.putString("picture","http://www.kxminteractive.com/Content/images/app_logos/secretMessage.png");
   params.putString("link", "http://www.kxminteractive.com/decrypt/");
  **mAsyncRunner.request(((temp2 == null) ? "me" : temp2) + "/feed",
                params, "POST", new WallPostRequestListener(),stream.publish);**
}
```